# Multiple Country RegEx Checker

Tags: regex, vba

How to change the below function so that It can take multiple patterns based on which country code is entered along with the postcode?

```
Function Checker(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    
    
    strPattern = "^[1-9]\d{3}$"
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange
        strReplace = ("Matched")
        
        With RegEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
        
        If RegEx.Test(strInput) Then
           Checker = RegEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            Checker = ("Not matched")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I am expecting that if say GB in cell "A1" then it checks the postcode in say "A2" and compares with the regEx pattern for the UK.
It will hold multiple countries as described above.

Comment: You could add a `Select Case` which populates `strPattern` based on which country was supplied, or use a lookup table on a worksheet to find the appropriate pattern.

Comment: Can you please explain how I'd do that? I'm lost on this. Yes the vlookup part is easy but how do I incorporate it into the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify the function to take two parameters. The first one
would be the country code and the second one the postal code.

I prefer removing the `Range` type and explicitly say it's some
`String` kind of data. A range can be multiple cells, so in this case
we could assume the second parameter for the country code could be
a range. But then you'll have to loop over each cell to test them
all with the regular expression. If one postal code is invalid then
stop the loop and return "Invalid postal code" or something similar.
If you need that, then I'll let you do it. But I think you just want
to validate a single postal code for a specific country code.

Here, I just did it for 4 countries, as an example. You'll have to
check under Wikipedia, like I did, to find the rules for each country.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function CheckPostalCode(strCountryCode As String, strPostalCode As String) As String
    ' Reference : Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim PostalCodeRegExp As New RegExp
    
    ' Prepare the postal code regular expression object.
    With PostalCodeRegExp
        .Global = False     ' We don't want multiple matches.
        .MultiLine = False  ' We don't want ^ and $ to match begin and end of lines.
        .IgnoreCase = False ' We want to be case sensitive.
    End With

    ' We'll get rid of spaces around and convert to uppercase for the tests below.
    Select Case Trim(UCase(strCountryCode))
        Case "CH", "CHE"
            PostalCodeRegExp.Pattern = "^[1-9][0-9]{3}$" ' DDDD but from 1000 to 9999 only
        Case "FR", "FRA"
            PostalCodeRegExp.Pattern = "^(?:0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-8])\d{3}$"
        Case "GB", "GBR", "UK"
            PostalCodeRegExp.Pattern = "^(([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]?|ASCN|STHL|TDCU|BBND|[BFS]IQQ|PCRN|TKCA) ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}|BFPO ?[0-9]{1,4}|(KY[0-9]|MSR|VG|AI)[ -]?[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{2} ?[0-9]{2}|GE ?CX|GIR ?0A{2}|SAN ?TA1)$"
            ' In case you want to make it case insensitive just for
            ' Great Britain then uncomment the line below.
'            PostalCodeRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
        Case "US", "USA"
            PostalCodeRegExp.Pattern = "^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$" ' DDDDD or DDDDD-DDDD
        Case Else
            CheckPostalCode = "Unknown country code"
            Exit Function
    End Select
    
    If PostalCodeRegExp.Test(strPostalCode) Then
        CheckPostalCode = "Valid postal code"
    Else
        CheckPostalCode = "Invalid postal code"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ohhhhh okay this looks more like it thank you so much! Yes I will just be doing one row at a time check, then will probably write a macro to drag the formula down to the last row. Can you check the code? I have the postcode in cell "A3" and the countrycode in "B3" but when I call the function by entering this in "C3" =checkpostalcode(A3,B3)  I get the error message of "compile error" - user defined type not defined

Comment: I put the country code as first parameter so you have to switch parameter orders or cell order in your formula. Also, respect the case and replace the `,` by a `;` in the Excel formula, so this will become `=CheckPostalCode(B3; A3)`

Comment: @JohnA: I also changed the function to handle 2 or 3 chars of country codes for more flexibility. I sorted them alphabetically for better readability.

Comment: same message when I switch the parameters, also when using ";" instead of "," it doesn't like it and suggests ":". Never seen a ; in a formula before - Am I missing something

Comment: And it highlights this section of the code: Dim PostalCodeRegExp As New RegExp

Comment: If you use the `RegExp` object, then **you have to add the reference** to this object in your VBA project. I had put the comment above especially for that. But as your code already had it, I thought that you already had something working! To add the reference, go to *Tools* -> *References* and add the one I mentionned.

Comment: @JohnA: about the formula separator, this might change according to the system language. Here, in the French part of Switzerland, we have to use the semicolon `;` (which I found stupid). In VBA programming, it's a comma `,` like in most programming languages. The suggested `:` is used to define cell ranges (in case you don't know).

Comment: Ohhhhhh what an idiot! yes I though it had been enabled in a previous project but it wasn't! Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!